# Handling Twilio Connection Errors

Tags: error-handling, twilio, sanic

How do I handle connection errors using the Twilio console? I have Twilio working with Sanic python and some connection errors are very difficult to diagnose in the application. When an error of this sort occurs, Twilio says "application error occurred". I would like to replace this with custom audio using the Twilio console? Is this possible? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a more detailed error description in the [Twilio Console](https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/guides/debugging-tools#:%7E:text=Found%20in%20your%20Twilio%20console,affected%20(and%20by%20whom).&text=B.,can%20dig%20into%20detailed%20logs.) when you select the **Monitor** tab in the side panel.

[image: error log]

Comment: Yes, I know about this and look at the logs on a daily basis. But is there a way through this console or by using TwiML templates to make Twilio play an audio message to the caller? For example, if an HTTP 500 error occurs, is it possible to have Twilio play a custom audio message? Or does all error handling have to be done in the application logic of the app connected to Twilio?